# Search by street number in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have several addresses I have to mark on Google Maps with a pointer.

The problem is that when I search for an address in the form of "Street Name" + "Street Number" the pointer just goes to the beginning of the street.

I'm pretty sure searching by street number (in my country) is possible, here is an example that works well: http://www.montevideobus.com.uy/

I would like to know if there is any way to add that functionality the search within maps.google since I have to be logged in to my maps account to add a site to the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that website stores street number in it's own database along with the coordinates. And it's using it's own search engine, not Google's. So if your search hit a street number and street, it just fetches the coordinate and points it on the map. In google maps, you can only search for street number if it's in the place address.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Street Number" <> "Street Name" instead of the other way around.    I just searched for one example that I know the position of, and it returned the correct place.

[image: Example of searching in My Maps for a street number]

This may not always work, eg in places where street numbers are not loaded into Google's own database, but it clearly works sometimes.

Comment: "Street Number" <> "Street Name" is working well.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/street-number-is-missing-practical-two-working-solutions/#post-10504105